# Обычный SSL сертификат на поддомен

Tags: сервер, ssl, сертификат, tls

Дамы и господа!
Возможно ли заказать и установить на сервер самый обычный сертификат (не Wildcard) на поддомен? То есть, при оформлении заказа так и указать, например, shop.example.com. Суть в том, что нужен лишь один поддомен, а покупать дорогущий Wildcard ради одного поддомена не гууд

Comment: Возможно конечно, а подробности уточняйте там где собрались его покупать (правда, непонятно, зачем его вам вообще покупать, если существует бесплатный wildcard от Let's Encrypt)

Comment: Let's Encrypt скоро будет "вне закона". С 21 года с ним на некоторых устройствах проблемы будут, поэтому с Let's Encrypt в ближайшее время лучше не связываться.

Comment: Не на «некоторых», а на старых андроидах, на которые всем плевать — пусть новые андроиды покупают или устанавливают сертификат вручную. Википедия и Stack Overflow используют Let's Encrypt и менять его вроде не планируют

Comment: Оой не скажите. Устройств с Андроид < 7.1 в настоящий момент всё ещё довольно много. Расслабиться можно будет, хотя бы, когда доля последних будет не более 1-2%. Но не по 10-15.

Comment: Поддомен - это такой же домен, как и домен второго уровня. Для продавцов сертификатов нет никакой разницы. Валидировать сможете? Тогда я не вижу никаких проблем.